# ggnet2 - how to offset/adjust edges of a network so they aren't plotted on top of eachother

Tags: r, networking, ggplot2

So I am using ggnet2 to plot a network, with nodes and edges, as per the vignette on github.

However, I would like to know if there is a way to adjust the positioning of the edges, so that they don't go from the centre of the vertex. [For example, in this plot here, you can see that some of the edges are going both to and from some of the vertices]https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DnCk.png

This network plot was generated using an example from the ggnet2 vignette:

```
library(GGally)
library(network)
library(sna)
library(ggplot2)    
ggnet2(network(rgraph(10, tprob = 0.25), directed = TRUE),
       arrow.size = 12, arrow.gap = 0.025)
```

What I would like is to be able to do something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSixB.jpg so that each A to B and B to A is visible separately. Any ideas how it can be done?